# Constraint violation (19) error in Active directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

When i m adding user oject in ldap, i m getting error of constraint voilation(19). I know the reason of problem. The problem is there are 'userprincipalname' and 'sAMAccountName' atrributes value already exist in ldap in same organization unit of same domain.

I want to know, is there any possibility to add duplicate value in user object in ldap?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The [sAMAccountName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute is a single-valued attribute and must be unique among all security principal objects within the **domain**.

The [UPN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677605(v=vs.85).aspx)  is a single-valued and indexed attribute and must be unique among all security principal objects within the **directory forest**.

Answer (score 1):

You used to be able to have [duplicate UPN's](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535779.aspx).

This changed in Windows Server 2012R2. I just ran into this also.